# Error in opening Template Builder

Tags: 2013-sp1, template-builder

I am getting a weird issue as below while trying to open the Template builder:

`Client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=utf-8', but expected 'text/xml'.`

While digging into the details, the error message is as below (getting this error message while trying to browse the Templating service in the browser):

```
Could not determine which version of ASP.NET Web Pages to use.
In order to use this site, specify a version in the site’s web.config file.
```

Following this, I have tried making below entry in the `app settings` in web.config for the Templating service:

```
<add key="webPages:Version" value="2.0"/>
```

This resolves the above mentioned error, however, gives another error as below:

```
Object moved to <a href="/templating/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2ftemplating%2fcompoundtemplatewebservice.asmx">here</a>
```

Any idea, why it might be happening? Any help will be appreciated.

PS:

I have already tried restarting Tridion Services, COM+ App and IIS for sake of it but no success. Also, I have tried re-installing the template builder. Further, the template builder can connect to other CMS environments but this error is happening on a specific environment only

Comment: Have you tried "repairing" the Tridion installation?

Comment: not yet, that's the last resort I guess ;) thanks Jaime

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you have configured IIS to do forms based authentication (which is not supported by Template Builder).

Comment: Thanks Rick for your feedback, I have re-checked and it is Windows Authentication only.

Comment: Something is trying to do a redirect to a login form, though. Do you have a SSO proxy/filter, maybe?

Comment: nopes...I did not have any..eventually I have to go and restored the VM image to make it wrk - that was a faster option